# Como uma especialização é implementada em um banco?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

No meu modelo de ER e no diagrama criei uma especialização para uma entidade denominada clientes, onde relaciona-se com as entidades físico e jurídico provenientes dessa especialização. Eu simplesmente crio as relações entre essas tabelas como se fosse um relacionamento normal ou tem algo mais que devo fazer na implementação?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [tour], você pode votar em tudo no site também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende da necessidade, mas essencialmente é isso mesmo. Tem os dados básicos na tabela da pessoa e os dados específicos na tabela do tipo de relação (imagino que terá outras além de clientes, caso contrário não faz muito sentido). A relação se dá por um ID da pessoa no cliente ou com um ID do cliente na pessoa (teria que ter uma coluna para cada tipo de relação ou algum truque mais elaborado). Se tem algo mais a fazer não posso dizer, depende da necessidade específica não explicitada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É que estou criando um software simples de controle de almoxarifado que vai conter (como um extra), uma rotina de vendas onde por sua vez poderia vender tanto para cliente fisico quanto para juridico, então eu relacionei assim: vendedor<vendas>cliente; e cliente, que encontra-se como uma entidade com especialização se relaciona com FISICO e JURIDICO. minha necessidade seria esta. Digo isto porque simplesmente não compreendi o que quis dizer com outras relações além de clientes.

Comment: Fornecedores, vendedores, funcionários, bancos, governo, transportadoras, etc. Se todas as pessoas cadastradas são clientes não tem porque especializar.

Comment: Então só para finalizar este debate, em que situação você recomendaria o uso de especialização? a falta de experiência no mercado de software faz com que eu não veja a necessidade de certas funções, isto é um projeto acadêmico.

Comment: Quando você não vê necessidade, não use. A especialização só faz sentido com existem casos especiais, quando alguma parte da estrutura do dado pode variar dependendo da situação.

Comment: ok então, obrigado pela ajuda!